# How to handle concurrent http request on node rest api?

Tags: node.js, concurrency, httprequest, backend, race-condition

I have a service which looks at a database boolean value, toggles the boolean value and then responds with the previous value. Eg: if the value was true, it is changed to false and true is sent as response.

The issue is that is there are two requests sent simultaneously (at the same time), the value sent is same for both. I guess this is a concurrency issue I am unable to solve. How can I ensure that the requests to my node server happen one at a time. Maybe some queue or something?

Comment: Where (in what make and model of database system) do you store this boolean value? Can you make that database toggle the value atomically, perhaps with a transaction? That's pretty much the only way to get rid of the race condition you describe.

Comment: The value is stored in firestore, i don't think toggling automatically would be possible for my problem though

Comment: I wrote [*atomically*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)), not *automatically.* You can indeed use transactions on Firestore.  Read this. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions